# CUDA equivalent of glDispatchComputeIndirect

Tags: cuda

What is the closest and efficient equivalent to a simple sequence chain of OpenGL glDispatchComputeIndirect() calls in Cuda on Pascal onwards?  Where the chain of dispatches/kernels dynamically varies the launch parameter sizes (blocks/threads etc).

Is glDispatchComputeIndirect() likely just a driver side API call overhead optimisation and not really a device side mechanism?

Is glDispatchComputeIndirect() equivalent to nested parallelism with a top level kernel of one 1 block and 1 thread doing a sequence of child kernel calls?

```
__device__ int blocks = 1;
__device__ int threads = 1;

__global__ void Parent()
{
 Child1<<<blocks, threads>>>(); // changes blocks/threads inside child
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
 Child2<<<blocks, threads>>>(); // changes blocks/threads inside child
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
...
}
```

Comment: Indirect dispatch isn't the same as dynamic parallelism as far as I am aware

Comment: If it isn't the same mechanisms, then I would be curious to know if it would be beneficial to expose similar to CUDA?  As a simple sequence of kernel dispatches in such a manner is quite common.  Knowing if using CUDA dynamic parallelism like this would always be the 'better option in theory' would be useful.  As I remember somewhere saying that indirect dispatches in opengl were only driver side optimisations for some hardware vendor generation at one point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is glDispatchComputeIndirect() likely just a driver side API call overhead optimisation and not really a device side mechanism?

Almost certainly.

> Is glDispatchComputeIndirect() equivalent to nested parallelism with a top level kernel of one 1 block and 1 thread doing a sequence of child kernel calls?

Almost certainly not.

Of course you would be free to use dynamic parallelism as a proxy for this functionality. It would also be possible to use mapped memory or managed memory to have the GPU write back to host accessible memory between kernel launches. But the same "pipeline" style indirect argument mechanism doesn't exist, as far as I am aware.

Comment: I think I should mark this as the answer.  But it would be very helpful to suggest for forward looking design decisions, given the first part of your answer that if/when dynamic parallelism becomes available to OpenGL compute shaders, that it likely would be the better alternative in chains of compute shaders to glDispatchComputeIndirect() as I suspect is the case?